# Need to mofify connection string without modifying the underlying webconfig

Tags: c#, web-config

I need to add a port to the connection string that is listed in my webconfig without actually changing the underlying webconfig file - having to do this each time I connect to the database is just fine but I'd prefer to do it only once if possible. I've seen a few posts were people are actually modifying the file (not possible) or completely rebuilding the string (also not really an awesome idea because of some complex hoodoo magic in it but not impossible).

It is not possible for me to put it in the web.config due to company restrictions. The project is in C# so I'll need a C# based solution.

Comment: You can't add a port number to the connection string due to company restrictions?

Comment: It is not possible for me to put it in the web.config due to company restrictions since it is plaintext on the server.

Comment: but your connection string is already in there

Comment: Bossman says "no" and I can't argue with him. (Not to mention, which I did, that the site dlls are technically plain text where it matters)

Comment: Creating transformation for web.config is also prohibited?

Comment: That just seems really odd, but then again, after years working in corporate environments, sadly not surprising :)

Comment: I can do anything except store the port number in the web config. Any other solution is viable as long as it isn't "plain text" on the server.

Comment: Subclass the ADO.NET connection, command and all other places where connections are used. Override all methods that take connection strings as a parameter. If you already are using System.Data.Common it shouldn't be too painful.

Comment: Centralize all access to ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings to a single method.